# Series representation of functions

Tags: fa.functional-analysis

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space, consisting of functions $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$. Let
$$
V = \left\{ f_J \in H: f_J= \sum_{j=1}^J c_j^{(J)} g_j, c_j^{(J)}\in\mathbb R, J\in \mathbb N \right\}
$$
where $g_j \in H$ for each $j\in \mathbb N$.

**My question:** If provided that $V$ is dense in $(H,\|\cdot\|_H)$, does any $f\in H$ admit a representation as follows?
$$
f = \sum_{j=1}^\infty c_j g_j 
$$
If not, what type of additional assumptions will be needed?

Comment: No. Polynomials are dense in $L^2(0,1)$.

Comment: and Gram orthonormalization of the sequence g_j  produces  a sequence h_j that makes it possible